# In C++ how can I extract members from an array and return an array of the member's type?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, preprocessor

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    Array<U> extract_(const Array<T>& array, std::function<U(const T&)> member)
    {
        Array<U> extracted;

        for (auto& item : array)
            extracted += member(item);

        return extracted;
    }
}


#define extract(container, member) detail::extract_(container, \
    std::function< typeof(typeof(container)::Type::element_type::member) (const typeof(container)::Type&)>( \
                   [&](const typeof(container)::Type& item){ return item->member; }))
```

So that's the algorithm I want to use to extract members from arrays. `Array<T>` is my homegrown array type, it handles bidness.

If you're allergic to macros, sorry, but it makes user code very clean.

What I want to do is if I have `Array<Size> sizeArray` with member `double Array<Size>::Length`, to be able to say `auto lengths = extract(sizeArray, Length);` and have `lengths` be of type `Array<double>`.

I already do something similar with

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    Array<T> filter_(const Array<T>& array, std::function<bool(const T&)> condition)
    {
        Array<T> filtered;

        for (auto& item : array)
            if (condition(item)) filtered += item;

        return filtered;
    }
}


// this macro creates a capturing lambda, the item to check is called 'item'
#define filter(container, condition) detail::filter_(container, \
    std::function<bool(const typeof(container)::Type&)>( \
                   [&](const typeof(container)::Type& item){ return condition; }))
```

I can do `auto turnedOff = filter(objects, !item->IsTurnedOn);` and it works really well, but it's returning the same type, so it's an easier task to solve.

Comment: What is "bidness"? And "If you're allergic to macros, sorry, but it makes user code very clean" - nope.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Maybe it meant to say "business"? As in, "I can handle my bidness".

Comment: So what is the question? Also, I'd suggest `decltype` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: Why don't you use `decltype`, given that you have access to at least C++11?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a "range" version of [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: Sorry, typeof(x) is #define typeof(x) remove_reference<decltype(x)>, I really_just_don't_like_how_pure_std_looks. The question is, it seems to be extracting a pure ```T```, and ```Array``` takes a ```const T&```, and that gives me error C2664, cannot convert from ```T``` to ```const T&```.

Comment: "If you're allergic to macros, sorry, but it makes user code very clean." - I respectfully disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use those macros. Please. For the love of god.

Now that we have that out of the way, here's a working solution, that doesn't involve the overhead of `std::function`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    int x;
    double y;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
auto extract(const std::vector<T>& vec, U T::* member)
{
    std::vector<U> result;
    result.reserve(vec.size());
    std::transform(
        std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::back_inserter(result),
        [member] (const T& val) { return val.*member; }
    );
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<A> as{{10, 3.14}, {42, 1.618}};
    auto result = extract(as, &A::x);
    for (auto x : result)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ewieLc

Comment: What's with all the opposition to these innocent macros? I mean I know I'll pay for this when modules come around because half of my stuff will stop working (which I'm hoping injection will help solve), but it's almost religious with you guys... I'm a solo developer, nobody else is looking at my code, and I like what I call "candy code", that is code that is not only structurally simple, but also _visually_ simple. all::the_std_decoration::doesn't help readability at all. My C++ looks like javascript thanks to these macros. Why not?

Comment: The call in question is `extract(as, &A::x)` vs `detail::extract_(container,    std::function< typeof(typeof(container)::Type::element_type::member) (const typeof(container)::Type&)>([&](const typeof(container)::Type& item){ return item->member; }))` . It just suggests misuse of the language in some way. There's situations where you can't get away from macros, but this is not one of them

Comment: Also, your solution means I'll have to add ```&A::``` in front of the member name, which is explicitly what I'm trying to avoid here. There's a reason I'm trying to encapsulate this in a macro, to automate this little nuance. ```auto extractedArray = extract(otherArray, MemberName);``` <-- this is specifically the goal.

Comment: Ok, just wrap my solution: `#define EXTRACT(container, member) extract(container, &decltype(container)::value_type::member)` . But now beware if `container` is some complex expression, your macro will explode. You can keep fixing these deficiencies, but it's still a band aid.

Comment: That's fair enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: "My C++ looks like javascript thanks to these macros" - oh dear $deity (if you believe in such). How is that a *good* thing? The strength of C++ is in the strict typing and namespacing of things. No way do you want it to look more dynamically typed and fluffy like JS. Arrgh, that just rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: Ok, maybe I went to far with that description. It looks more like C#, or D. I'm a simple man and I like simple words. :) I'm working on a large project, I have a lot of words to read, so it's basically an effort management strategy. Candy code for me is as useful as comments. Just the fact that I visually design how it looks means that I can find things that little bit faster and understand larger patterns of things quicker. And yes, I've had to fine-tune a little how much is implied. But as a solo dev, what is implied is usually systematic and obvious. It's limited to a few algos and types.

Comment: What I meant by "looks like javascript" is that as part of my simplification strategy, I've ended up moving a lot of functions from a C++ ClassName::MemberMethod() style to a C globalFunction() style. After some getting used to, this showed me that a lot of stuff just doesn't need to be conceptually classed. When functions are free-floating, I program more "at the speed of thought", so to say. Then some JS rubbed off on me and I started camelCasing() my functions (normally I CapitalCase() them). So the visual progression was C++ -> C# -> C -> JavaScript. It's still C++, just... cleaner. :)